# how can i group by field value?

Tags: mysql

how can i group by one field start by value 0
    eg.

```
select * from t;
id, check_id, user_name
1,  0,        user_a
2,  1,        user_a
3,  2,        user_a
1,  0,        user_a
2,  1,        user_a
3,  3,        user_a
1,  0,        user_b
2,  1,        user_b
3,  3,        user_b
```

group by check_id by start by value 0 per group

```
user_name, check_info
user_a,    0-1-2
user_a,    0-1-3
user_b,    0-1-3
```

how can i group by?

Comment: Your table design makes it very hard to write a query for that. You are having duplicate rows (e.g. `1 - 0 - user_a` is duplicated). You should consider changing the structure of the table. (I can't help you with that since you didn't give us an explanation of your table context/data requirements)

Comment: While the basic idea is possible the biggest issue is you have nothing to define the order of the rows (ie, the order of the rows, and hence why user_a appears twice in your output is basically random - no reason why they will appear in that order).

Comment: @Rahautos This will not produce the expected result set.

Comment: I bet, there is no query that produce expected resultset based on your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i read in the question : *group by one field start by value 0*

Then, you can try this.

```
select user_name,group_concat(distinct check_id order by check_id asc separator '-') check_info
from (
    select id,check_id,user_name,
    case when check_id = 0 then
        @rn := @rn+1
    else
        @rn := @rn
    end as unique_id
    from t
    inner join (select @rn := 0) as tmp
    order by user_name
) as tbl
group by user_name,unique_id
```

This will group by for every records start by 0 and order by user_name.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want....maybe. It does work but is relying on the records coming back in the appropriate order when selected from the table (and that is NOT certain to occur).

```
SELECT user_name, GROUP_CONCAT(check_id ORDER BY grouping, check_id SEPARATOR '-')
FROM
(
    SELECT id, check_id, user_name, @grouping:=if(id > @prev_id, @grouping, @grouping + 1) AS grouping, @prev_id:=id
    FROM t
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT @grouping:=0, @prev_id:=0
    ) sub0
) sub1
GROUP BY user_name, grouping
```

It works by returning the rows and using variables to assign a grouping to them (so when the id gets smaller it adds one to the grouping value), then does a GROUP BY on the user name and the grouping value.

But really you need to have the grouping value somehow stored with your data in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that `id` is an *auto-increment* field, then you can use:

```
SELECT user_name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(check_id ORDER BY check_id SEPARATOR '-') AS check_info
FROM (
SELECT id, check_id, user_name,
       @grp := IF (@uname = user_name,
                   IF (check_id = 0, @grp + 1, @grp),
                   IF (@uname := user_name, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)) AS grp
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @grp := 0, @uname := '') AS vars
ORDER BY id) AS t
GROUP BY user_name, grp
```

Variables are used to identify slices of consecutive records, within each `user_name` partition, starting by `0`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d85d6/7)

Comment: [Err] 1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='